# Why and when "Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker" is triggered when I use parallelStream in Java11

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, java-11, forkjoinpool

I have a java11 app running a long time and recently I find this occurs more and more day by day

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker

I know I should not put too much blocking operation within `parallelStream` but I should try my best to accelerate the code above so that I response my request asap.

```
IntStream.range(0, nums).parallel().forEach((x) -> {
   IntStream.range(0, nums2).parallel().forEach((y) -> {
      IntStream.range(0, 20).parallel().forEach((z) -> {
    // do some business logic which use jni and cost cpu much ,mean rtt is about 400ms and sometimes upper99 could reach 10s.
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: “*I know I should not put too much blocking operation within parallelStream*…”—then you understand the issue. “*…but I should try my best to accelerate the code above*”—of course, you should, but how does this justify violating the principle mentioned in the first part of the sentence? You add blocking calls to accelerate the code?

Comment: Maybe blocking operation is not very correct, it should be time cost operation. Using parallelStream indeed help me make better use of cpu and accelerate the total process above of each request  than I remove parallel() after the second IntStream

Comment: But the exception message indicates that there *are* blocking operations. When I try to provoke that exception deliberately, I need more than 60,000,000 blocking operations before F/J refuses to accept a new job.

Comment: @Holger How can you reproduce this exception? Can you appreciated share your sample code to me ? I could not reproduce it with Thread.sleep() to mock business logic time costing and I found only 3 threads of ForkJoinPool.common is used,all other threads are all my submitting threads.

Comment: You can not reproduce it with `Thread.sleep()`, as only managed blocking operations, i.e. those declared to the Fork/Join pool may start a compensation thread. Like `CompletableFuture.join()` or a parallel stream’s terminal operation waiting for its worker threads or a custom implementation of `ManagedBlocker`. However, I just noticed that the exception message differs. Apparently, F/J attempts queuing in my setups. The particular code within F/J is very complex; I don’t know under which circumstances the “limit exceeded” message will actually occur, but there must be a high number of blockers

Comment: @Holger what terminal operation do you mean? I have no use of CompletableFuture.join() nor custom implementation of ManagedBlocker

Comment: `forEach` is a terminal operation, which will wait until all worker threads have completed. If that’s the only blocking, I don’t see, how this could lead to your exception under normal circumstances. Perhaps, you are using a custom `ForkJoinPool`?

Comment: The size of commonPool thread increases at the daytime and decreases at the midnight as our business requests, I found the statuses of all commonPool threads be TIMED_WAITING or WAITING all the time, I have no idea why this happens.